# Recently started showing Salesforce web api error for V49.0 "The requested resource does not exist". There is no issue in the URL

Tags: rest-api, error, post, get

Salesforce web api GET and POST both were working OK before. Suddenly from today started giving following error. Noticed in the API setup API version is changed but after updating newer version code still same error.

https://XXXX.salesforce.com//services/data/v59.0/sobjects/Order_Product_Shipment__c/XXXXXXXX?_HttpMethod=PATCH

[
{
"errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": "The requested resource does not exist"
}
]

Comment: Double check the Id that you've obscured through the normal web ui. This would be the message to expect if that particular record is deleted.

Comment: Yes, I reverified it. Issue is still there. We are using version API call version 49.0 but app has version 59.0. Tried both version numbers but not solving the problem. Is there any specific settings needed on the server after version changed to newer version?

Comment: You have `...//services...`  - is that a typo? If not, that is your issue

Comment: It has found that web api url changed not sure how come as salesforce did not send any email. New url looks like "https://MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data" but the original link was "https://otherdomainName.salesforce.com/services/data"

Comment: You should post this as an answer instead of a comment. Yes, you can officially answer your own questions!

Answer (score 0):

It has found that web api url changed not sure how come as salesforce did not send any email. New url looks like
"MyDomainName.my.salesforce.com/services/data" but the original link was "otherdomainName.salesforce.com/services/data"

After connecting with salesforce customer support for the url change issue, following is salesforce reply.

"As your org has been migrated to hyperforce due to which your instance has changed. Earlier it used to be "bbbb" now it has been changed to "aaaa" which caused this API call to break."
It is recommended to use the my domain name instead of instance-specific url so you don't have to face any similar issue in future.

Comment: Hard-coded references to instance names (xxx.salesforce.com) are a bad practice. Migration to Hyperforce exposes this bad practice. In many notices and warnings related to migration that were sent to customers, all of them referred to [How to Prepare for Org Migration doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386897&type=1) 
. The doc talks about this issue in the very first 'What do I need to do' question